# SQL Query Slow with Count Distinct Subquery in Join Clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

Have the below query which works great without this subquery in the join case. Any ideas on more efficient ways to do this? It's unclear if this is occurring because the subquery is running for all records in items and not respecting the where = cms.orderno... thanks for any help!

Subquery:

```
select count(distinct(ship_to)) 
from items 
where cms.orderno = items.orderno and ship_to <> 0
```

Full Query:

```
select
    cms.custnum,
    cms.odr_date,
    cms.orderno,
    internetid,
    ltrim(rtrim(cust.firstname))+' '+ltrim(rtrim(cust.lastname)) as    recipient,
    ord_total,
    ordertype,
    order_st2,
    websitestatdesc,
    holdcode
from 
    cms
    join statdesc on cms.order_st2 = statdesc.statcode
    join items on cms.orderno = items.orderno
    join cust on 
        case 
            when (
                select count(distinct(ship_to)) 
                from items
                where cms.orderno = items.orderno and ship_to <> 0
            ) = 1 then items.ship_to 
            when cms.shipnum <> 0 then cms.shipnum
            else cms.custnum 
        end = cust.custnum
where 
    cms.custnum = 3300 
    and statdesc.stattype = 'O'
group by 
    cms.orderno,
    cms.custnum,
    cms.odr_date,
    internetid,
    firstname,
    lastname,
    ord_total,
    ordertype,
    order_st2,
    websitestatdesc,
    holdcode
order by cms.orderno desc
```

Comment: Run the query in SSMS and have it show the execution plan and then share it here https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/. Also while you are at it, try the performance optimiser in SSMS - it could be as simple as a missing index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, do you have an index on column `orderno` in table `items`? I imagine you aren't returning many rows... so a missing index here could be a killer.

Then I would be inclined to modify the query to avoid needing a `group by` as follows (assuming I understand your intention of course):

```
select
  cms.custnum
  , cms.odr_date
  , cms.orderno
  , internetid
  , ltrim(rtrim(cust.firstname))+' '+ltrim(rtrim(cust.lastname)) as recipient
  , ord_total
  , ordertype
  , order_st2
  , websitestatdesc
  , holdcode
from (
  select *, (
      select count(distinct(ship_to)) 
      from items
      where cms.orderno = items.orderno and ship_to <> 0
    ) distinct_ship_to_count
    , (
      select top 1 ship_to 
      from items
      where cms.orderno = items.orderno and ship_to <> 0
    ) distinct_ship_to
    from cms
) cms
join statdesc on cms.order_st2 = statdesc.statcode
--join items on cms.orderno = items.orderno
join cust on 
  case 
    when cms.distinct_ship_to_count = 1 then cms.distinct_ship_to
    when cms.shipnum <> 0 then cms.shipnum
    else cms.custnum 
  end = cust.custnum
where cms.custnum = 3300 
and statdesc.stattype = 'O'
--group by cms.orderno, cms.custnum, cms.odr_date, internetid, firstname, lastname, ord_total, ordertype, order_st2, websitestatdesc, holdcode
order by cms.orderno desc
```

Comment: well done! This did it. Yes, this is an index on items.orderno... in this example, the query returns 92 records. It was taking 10 seconds to execute, now less than 1 second with your help. Thanks!